# Static object declaration only causing no error

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Why the code is not causing compile error?

```
 #include<iostream>
 class x{
  private:
   int v;
  public:
   x():v(7){};
 };

class b{
 private:
  static x as;
  int a;
 public:
  b():a(8){};
};
//x b::as;

int main(){
  b g;
  return 0;
 }
```

Even after commenting the particular line `x b::as` code works which I think it should as I haven't define/initiate my static object which is necessary. Why is it so?

And what if I initiate non-static object using static object like `static x asd; x bv=asd;` ?

Comment: It does not not cause a error until you use it (b::as) in your code. Then, linker will not able to find it's definition and cause a unresolved reference error (`undefined reference to b::as`).

Comment: @VictorPolevoy what happens if i initiate non-static object using static object like static x asd; x bv=asd;

Comment: compiles just fine in msvc++ and gcc

Comment: i want to know what happens behind scenes? is it legal to copy static object to non static object.what can be its possible pitfalls?

Comment: @AnkitSingh: None. Why would there be? And why are you asking a second question?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  : to be better just like you

Answer (score 2):

The program compiles and runs fine because it doesn't actually violate any rules. The key rule here is, in [basic.def.odr]:

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable **that is odr-used**
>   in that program; no diagnostic required.

In your program, `b::as` is not *odr-used* yet. However, as soon as you use it somewhere (maybe you take its address, or try to access `as.v`, etc), then you violate this condition because you didn't provide a definition for `as`.

Comment: i got that.now lets suppose what happens i initialise non static object with static object

Comment: i think as.v cant be directly accessed as it is private member of the class

Comment: Also worth it to point out -- even if you violate ODR your program may appear to "compile and run fine" but it still has UB. So OPs observation doesn't count for much particularly in this case

Answer (score 1):

1. It wil not ever cause a error until you use it (`b::as`) in your code. Then, linker will not able to find it's definition and cause a unresolved reference error:

   > undefined reference to b::as
2. If you will try to initialize a non-static class member by static one, here is the same behaviour:

   1. If you define your static member here is no error.
   2. If you don't do that, there would be a unresolved reference error.

      ```
      class b {
      private:
          static x as;
          int a = b::as;
      public:
         b():a(8){};
      };
      x b::as; // this is now correct but if you comment this, you should can't initialize `b::a` with `b::as` then because it will cause a unresolved reference error.
      ```